# Capturar valor de select con Jquery

Tags: jquery

Tengo el siguiente formulario pero no logro capturar el valor del select para poder enviarlo mediante ajax al servidor con un metodo POST pero no logro capturar ese valor.

```html
<form id="medicForm" class="col s12">
                                <div class="row let"><br>
                                  <div class="input-field col s6">
                                      <input placeholder="Código del medicamento" id="codigo" type="text" required>
                                      <label for="codigoMedicamento">Nombre Medicamento:</label>
                                  </div>
                                    <div class="input-field col s6">
                                        <input placeholder="Nombre del medicamento" id="nombre" type="text" required>
                                        <label for="nombreMedicamento">Nombre Medicamento:</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="input-field col s6">
                                        <select id="sintoma">
                                            <option value="0" disabled selected>Seleccionar</option>
                                            <option value="Otro">Otro</option>
                                            <option value="Acides">Acides</option>
                                            <option value="Alergia">Alergia</option>
                                            <option value="Antiinflamatorio">Antiinflamatorio</option>
                                            <option value="Bloqueador">Bloqueador</option>
                                            <option value="Diarrea">Diarrea</option>
                                            <option value="Dolor">Dolor</option>
                                            <option value="Golpe">Golpe</option>
                                            <option value="Gripe">Gripe</option>
                                            <option value="Higado">Higado</option>
                                            <option value="Hongos">Hongos</option>
                                            <option value="Infeccion">Infeccion</option>
                                            <option value="Malestar">Malestar</option>
                                            <option value="Nervios">Nervios</option>
                                            <option value="Presion">Presion</option>
                                            <option value="Resfrio">Resfrio</option>
                                            <option value="Tos">Tos</option>
                                            <option value="Viagra">Viagra</option>
                                        </select>
                                        <label>Sintoma:</label>
                                    </div>
</form>
```

Y mi esquema de Jquery es el siguiente pero no logro capturar el valor del select hago una funcion .change() para capturar el valor pero aun no almacena dicho valor:

```js
$(document).ready(()=>{

  $('#medicForm').on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var codigo = $('#codigo').val();
    var nombre = $('#nombre').val();
    var sintoma = $('#sintoma').change(function(){
      return $('select[id=sintoma]').val();
    });

    console.log(sintoma);
  });

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si lo que querés es obtener el valor del `select` al enviar el formulario, tenés que hacer lo mismo que hiciste con el resto de los inputs:

```js
$('#medicForm').on('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var codigo = $('#codigo').val();
  var nombre = $('#nombre').val();
  var sintoma = $('#sintoma').val();

  console.log(sintoma);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="medicForm" class="col s12">
  <div class="row let"><br>
    <div class="input-field col s6">
      <input placeholder="Código del medicamento" id="codigo" type="text" required>
      <label for="codigoMedicamento">Nombre Medicamento:</label>
    </div>
    <div class="input-field col s6">
      <input placeholder="Nombre del medicamento" id="nombre" type="text" required>
      <label for="nombreMedicamento">Nombre Medicamento:</label>
    </div>
    <div class="input-field col s6">
      <select id="sintoma">
        <option value="0" disabled selected>Seleccionar</option>
        <option value="Otro">Otro</option>
        <option value="Acides">Acides</option>
        <option value="Alergia">Alergia</option>
        <option value="Antiinflamatorio">Antiinflamatorio</option>
        <option value="Bloqueador">Bloqueador</option>
        <option value="Diarrea">Diarrea</option>
        <option value="Dolor">Dolor</option>
        <option value="Golpe">Golpe</option>
        <option value="Gripe">Gripe</option>
        <option value="Higado">Higado</option>
        <option value="Hongos">Hongos</option>
        <option value="Infeccion">Infeccion</option>
        <option value="Malestar">Malestar</option>
        <option value="Nervios">Nervios</option>
        <option value="Presion">Presion</option>
        <option value="Resfrio">Resfrio</option>
        <option value="Tos">Tos</option>
        <option value="Viagra">Viagra</option>
      </select>
      <label>Sintoma:</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

(te falta cerrar un `</div>` antes del `</form>`).